# Attention! box for edit suggestions appearing because most conflicted with a subsequent edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

So i got the yellow attention box at the top when i went to suggest an edit (i wasn't really but i went to edit because the question said "here is my code" and there was nothing so i though they didn't format it but that wasn't the case, they just didn't add anything). the message was

> Attention! Some of your previous edits were rejected. While reasonable edits may be rejected for many reasons outside of your control, you should review your recently-rejected edits before continuing.

looking at my [previous edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028804/memor-x?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) i only see 2 rejected edits by other users (whether i agree with their reasoning or not is irrelevant here) all my other suggestion rejects were rejected by Community because

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

which i assume came from me submitting an edit after another edit was made while i was working.

With this warning appearing now do i run the risk of entering into an edit ban? if so then would further Community Edit Rejections like the ones i've been getting end up contributing to said ban? if so shouldn't these rejected edits be exempt because these edits i don't think are even getting into the review que

Comment: Rejections due to "conflicted with a subsequent edit" should not count towards an edit ban. But it is strange that you got the warning. Do you have rejected edits on deleted posts?

Comment: @S.L.Barth i don't know. i don't recall any or whether they are conflicted with a subsequent edit rejections or review que rejections

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281598/does-it-count-against-me-if-community-rejects-my-edit-because-it-conflicted-wi)

Answer (score 1):

> With this warning appearing now do i run the risk of entering into an edit ban?

No. The warning itself doesn't count towards the edit ban - it's just a heads-up like "hey, you'd better check out your previous suggested edits".

> would further Community Edit Rejections like the ones i've been getting end up contributing to said ban?

You won't get banned from editing if you make lots of suggested edits that "conflict with subsequent edits". However, edits rejected for the following reason count towards the edit ban:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

---

**TL;DR:** Don't worry about the message if your edits are rejected due to conflicts with subsequent edits.